# hitting a wall with debugging; not a coding issue as much as one of programming experience

Tags: python, debugging

Working on a small area of circle prog. I have not been able to solve the problems arising in the debugging phase. Errors like "variable referenced outside..." and others that will not process a simple equation (ex. radius = area / PI * radius). I try numerous ways to get around the problem, short of rewriting the whole prog, but nothing works. My solutions either create a new problem or don't solve the problem at hand. I've studied python for three weeks but do have coding experience w/COBOL so I understand the concepts of functions and flow charting.

What do you do when you don't have the mind or tools to solve the problem? I want to solve these issues on my own. Asking for help is wise but eventually you have to fly on your own.

Thanks for any help.

Flux

Addition:

Area of Circle and Radius:

```
# Exercise 1 Area of Circle
# This prog will ask for circle dimensions and compute
# area/radius for the user, then display figures, and
# allow to repeat.

import sys
import pdb
PI = 3.14
radius = 0


print ('''Welcome to Ursavion, the leader in math apps
This app allows you to quickly and easily find
either the area or radius for a circle.''')
print ( )


def chooseAR ( ):
    print ('Do you need to find circle area or circle radius? Enter A/a or A/r. ')
    choice = input ( )
    if choice in ['A', 'a']:
        areaSol ( )

    elif choice in ['R', 'r']:
        radSol (radius)

    else:
        print ('Please enter either A/a or R/r. ')
        chooseAR ( )

def areaSol ( ):
    radius = 0
    radius = input ('What is the radius of the circle? ')
    radius = int (radius)

    area = PI * radius**2 

    radius = str(radius)
    area = str(area)

    print ('The area of a circle with radius ' + radius + ' is ' + area + ' units '         squared')
    print ( )
    print ('Calculate another? y/n ')
    again = input ( )
    if again in [ 'y', 'n']:
        chooseAR ( )

    else:
        print ('Thank you for using this app.')


def radSol (radius):
    #pdb.set_trace( )                   #r = 1.128 for A = 4 
    area = input ('What is the area of the circle? ')
    area = int(area)
    radius = int(radius)

    radius = area / 3.14 * radius       #prog will not eval this formula; float pt prob


    radius = str(radius)
    area = str(area)    

   print ('The radius of a circle with area ' + str(area) + ' is ' + str(radius) + '   units')
   print ( )
   again = input ('Calculate another? y/n ')
   if again in ['Y', 'y', 'N', 'n']:
       chooseAR( )

   else:
        print ('Thank you for using this app.')


chooseAR ( )  # This function is one problem. Program initializes all 
              # functions on first pass, but it needs "chooseAR" here to allow the 
              # program to start, else it never runs; however, the "chooseAR" sets up
              # an infinite loop if it exists here.
```

Comment: When nothing makes sense, google the error message and start digging.

Comment: Also, please tag with the language "python" and also post some code and exact error messages. Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is a good place to get help. But the more information you can give us the easier it is to lend some help. Please post the code that you have, and any error messages. If you can isolate the section of code that you think is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Well, from what I understand, you don't want to provide a specific code example, because you want to figure out how to do debugging on your own? It's kind of difficult to answer without knowing more about **what** you are trying to debug.

There are several types of problems that may arise when coding

- Typos
- Syntax errors
- Logic errors

### Typos

Don't laugh, this will be most common errors you encounter. How to debug them? Really the best way is to proof read your code. It also highly depends on the IDE. If you are developing with something like Microsoft Studio IDE, or Apple's Xcode IDE, it will give you hints on what you are trying to type, and you can auto-complete the typing. If the hint doesn't show up... your are probably making a typo.

For things you program in a text editor (like shell, python, etc), those options are usually not available. One trick is to copy-paste your variable names. This way you won't make an accidental typo. Be careful where you copy-paste from... you don't want to paste a previous typo all over the code :)

Sometimes, you can be staring right at the typo, and not see it. Best approach is to examine your variables. Again, with various IDEs, there are in-built debuggers that let you do that. On others, just echo/print/output your variables and examine their value yourself. If you are expecting a value inside a variable, and it is coming up blank (or better yet, with an "undefined variable" type error), you can now focus on seeing if you have a typo in the name

### Syntax Errors

Syntax errors are actually easier to see, as they usually produce some kind of error (either at compile-time, or at run-time). The more experience you have with the language, the less syntax errors you will make. Google for code examples and manual pages for the specific constructs you are trying to use and understand their syntax. Stackoverflow is also a great source for this. Don't be afraid to ask a question about a syntax error. The explanation may make things so much clearer for you, rather then blindly using trial-n-error.

Usually, just googling the error message in quotes will give you all you need to know to fix it.

### Logic errors

These are the most difficult to debug, as they are not computer errors, but problem with your design. Ability to troubleshoot these comes purely from experience and ability to program. Stackoverflow is a perfect place to ask a question, and others will provide you possible solutions and workarounds. Even if the solutions don't work for your case, it **will** get your mind thinking in the right direction and give you ideas.

If you have experience, go to previous programs you have written and see how you solved similar issue in there.

### Example

So, in your example, you didn't give us much:
`radius = area / PI * radius`
That is actually not a simple statement. There is:

- variable assignment
- variable reference
- arithmetic operation
- operation precedence

Any one of those could be giving problems. So to debug, simplify the expression first:

- Print the variables first
  `print area`
  `print PI`
  `print radius`

You should see the output with expected values. If any of them is blank, you probably typoed a variable name. Even if it is spelled correctly here, maybe you misspelled it when you first declared it and gave it a value.

- Next, do a simple operation, like `temp = PI * radius` and then print the result `print temp`. Verify that this value is as what's expected. You may have a syntax error because of data-types compatibility (not the case here)

But to conclude this, based on your reference to "variable referenced outside", it may be a scope issue. Usually you cannot reference a variable that is declared outside of it's scope (for example, a variable that is declared inside a function cannot be referenced by the same higher block that is calling this function), but things like this are in the language definition. You just need to know the language that you are programming in.

If you are new to programming, and reading a giant language definition book is too daunting, you should at least read up about these things that are common in every language (yet different)

- Variable declaration and reference
- Operators
- Variable scope
- Common constructs
- Function declaration and invocation

Comment: I've read up on functions some more. As I can see, variable references occur from local to regional (blocks within blocks) to global.

Answer (score 2):

As you yourself rightly say, this has to do something with experience. The more experienced you get, the less likely you will have to ask someone about every minor problem.

But in order to gain that experience and to progress you will have to get past these minor issues, so asking is definetly a valid means to do so.

As long as you try to learn from your mistakes (if one can call them so), all should be good.

Anyway, some debuggers can be a real pain in the *cough*.

Comment: Also, don't be afraid of using the languages equivalent of a print line. Bjarne Stroustrup is rumored to still use them, Kernighan has a quote about the best debugging tools being careful thought, and use of many print line statements.

Comment: I added code so you could see what I'm talking about. Thanks.